# Spring JpaTransactionManager with Nested transactions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I have following spring configuration.

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="true" />
</bean>



<bean id='entityManagerFactory'
    class='org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean'>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="test" />
    <property name='dataSource' ref='dataSource' />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
             <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
 <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb" />
  <property name="username" value="test" />
  <property name="password" value="test" />
</bean>
```

And i have created following entity.

```
@Entity(name="testtable")
public class Testtable implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
private int testid;

@Column(length=10)
private String description;

public Testtable() {
}

public int getTestid() {
    return this.testid;
}

public void setTestid(int testid) {
    this.testid = testid;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return this.description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

}
```

Now I want to test the nested transaction behavior with this setup. So I have created following test class.

```
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=false)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:context-test.xml")
public class TableTest {

@Autowired
private TesttableRepository testtableRepository;

@Test
@Transactional
public void testMethod()
{
    Testtable entry = new Testtable();
    entry.setDescription("ABC");
    entry = testtableRepository.save(entry);
    TestObj t = new TestObj(testtableRepository);

    t.testNestedTransactional();


entry.setDescription("ABCEE");
 testtableRepository.save(entry);
assertNotNull(entry.getTestid());
}


}

public class TestObj {

public TestObj(TesttableRepository testtableRepository){
    this.testtableRepository = testtableRepository;
}

private TesttableRepository testtableRepository;

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NESTED )
public void testNestedTransactional(){
    Testtable entry1 = new Testtable();

        entry1.setDescription("RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR");
         testtableRepository.save(entry1);

}
```

}

The `testNestedTransactional()` method in `TestObj.java` should fail because of database constraint violation (Max length for field description is 10). Even though this method fail I expect "ABCEE" value to be saved in database. Is this correct with nested transaction behavior? How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: First your test is flawed as you are constructing a `TestObj` yourself instead of using a spring managed instance. I also believe your understanding go a nested transaction is flawed. I suggest you do some studying for that. I guess you just want a new transaction instead of nested tx.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you create `TestObj` manually. You should do it using Spring context (declare it in context as a bean and autowire in the test).

Spring will wrap this bean in a proxy to make it transactional. In your case it is a plain old Java object without transactional behavior.

Comment: yes,i have made TestObj as a bean.But still I have the same issue

Comment: @user1516815 there is any exception in logs? Using nested transactions assume using of savepoints. Actually, i am not sure that it is have sufficient support in spring/hibernate. If you just need behavior described in your question, make propagation of inner method REQUIRES_NEW. And if you want to figure out how NESTED works, try to use low-level JDBC savepoints.

Comment: What are the implementation of jpaDialect supporting JDBC savepoints?Can anyone suggest?

Comment: I used org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect with Mysql InnoDb.Now I'm getting error "JpaDialect does not support savepoints - check your JPA provider's capabilities"

Comment: Can you update the question (code) to provide more specific info?