# Nested transactional behavior with JpaTransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I want to achieve nested transaction behavior with my spring application.
Following are my Spring configuration.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml"></property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="hibernatePersistenceUnit" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
     <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
             <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="true" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"  proxy-target-class="true" />
```

Also I have two spring managed beans.

```
public class Bean1{

 @Autowired
private TesttableRepository testtableRepository;

@Autowired
private Bean2 bean2;

 @Transactional
 public void testMethod()  {
    Testtable entry = new Testtable();
    entry.setDescription("ABC");
    entry = testtableRepository.save(entry);


try{
 bean2.testNestedTransactional();
}catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e){
 e.printStackTrace();

}
    entry.setDescription("ABCEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE");
    testtableRepository.save(entry)
}

}

public class Bean2{

 @Autowired
 private TesttableRepository testtableRepository;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NESTED)
public void testNestedTransactional()  {
    Testtable entry1 = new Testtable();
    entry1.setDescription("SSSS");
    testtableRepository.save(entry1);
}
}
```

This is my Entity class.

```
@Entity(name="testtable")
public class Testtable implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
private int testid;

@Column(length=10)
private String description;

public Testtable() {
}

public int getTestid() {
    return this.testid;
}

public void setTestid(int testid) {
    this.testid = testid;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return this.description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

}
```

Since testMethod() in bean1 object fails when saving "ABCEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE" (Max length of description field is set to 10) I want to rollback changes done by testNestedTransactional() in Bean2.But with configuration it doesn't work for me. Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring JpaTransactionManager with Nested transactions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27395140/spring-jpatransactionmanager-with-nested-transactions)

Comment: Please don't ask the [same question twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27395140/spring-jpatransactionmanager-with-nested-transactions)!

Comment: That's because you are eating up the exception in the testMethod() with a try catch. What happens if you remove the try catch block?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter,because exception occurs in outer method.So nested transaction should be rollback.